# How to typeset this matrix equation using simple LaTeX tools

Tags: matrices, brackets

Here is the output I need:

[image: Matrix equation]

The closest I could get is this:

```latex
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    & \\
   v & \\
    & \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   w &  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

Which outputs this:

[image: bad output]

But you can see there are obvious differences that I need:

1. `v` and `w` which are center-aligned inside the brackets.
2. The first matrix is a column matrix, and the second one is a row matrix and is located on the upper right side of the first matrix.

By "simple LaTeX tools" I mean preferably not using any special package, as I need the code in a Jupyter Notebook.

For your information, I also used [MathPix](https://mathpix.com/), but it couldn't recognize the details I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  A theme I notice in the answers is that they've deleted your `&`.  This was causing your left-alignment and wasn't really necessary to begin with.

Comment: @Teepeemm Hello! Thank you for the tip. Yes, that solves the left-alignment problem. But shifting the second matrix upwards would still be a problem, and I could solve it with the help of the accepted answer.

Comment: The simplest solution is `\begin{bmatrix}\\v\\\\\end{bmatrix}^{\begin{bmatrix}w\end{bmatrix}}` - this also works perfectly in MathJax, which is how Jupyter notebooks typeset LaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nest the second `bmatrix` as the first element of a `matrix` environment and add to the latter two empty rows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \\
   \; v\; \\
     \\
  \end{bmatrix}\!\!
\begin{matrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \; w\; \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \\{}\\ {}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Let TeX do the computations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A=
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{\hbox{$#$}\vfil\cr
  \begin{bmatrix} \mbox{} \\ \quad v \quad  \\ \mbox{} \end{bmatrix} \cr
  \begin{bmatrix} \quad w \quad \end{bmatrix} \cr
}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps nesting array-environments and `\vphantom` in some places does the trick—but I assume there are much better solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
$A=\left[%
     \begin{array}{c}%
       {\vphantom{\left[\begin{array}{c}w\end{array}\right]}}\\
       {v}\\
       {\vphantom{\left[\begin{array}{c}w\end{array}\right]}}\\
     \end{array}%
   \right]\mathclose{}\  %
   \kern-\arraycolsep
   \begingroup
   % Adjust \arraycolsep to regulate the horizontal gaps between "[" and "w" and "]"
   \arraycolsep=1\arraycolsep\relax
   \kern-\arraycolsep
   \begin{array}{c}%
     {\mathopen{}\left[\begin{array}{c}w\end{array}\right]}\\
     {\vphantom{v}}\\
     {\vphantom{\left[\begin{array}{c}w\end{array}\right]}}\\
   \end{array}\kern-\arraycolsep\endgroup=A$
\end{document}
```

[image]